# Unknown Host exception while trying to connect using Appium Driver

Tags: selenium, appium

We are trying to connect to perfecto mobile cloud using Appium driver. But getting unknown host exception. Although the url is reachable in browser but not when we ping. Below is the url:
citi.perfectomobile.com

Adding code snippet that we are trying

```
package appiumDemo;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;

public class FirstDemo {
    static AppiumDriver driver;
    static String host="xyz.perfectomobile.com"; 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
         capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
         capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "10.2.1");
         capabilities.setCapability("manufacturer", "Apple");
         capabilities.setCapability("model", "iPhone-5S");
         capabilities.setCapability("user","k*******@****.com");
         capabilities.setCapability("password","********");
         driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://" + host + "/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
}
```

Below is the error trace

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.UnknownHostException: xyz.perfectomobile.com
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'C*******', ip: '169.***.***.***', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:87)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:111)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:78)
    at appiumDemo.FirstDemo.main(FirstDemo.java:25)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: xyz.perfectomobile.com
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1255)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1171)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:343)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: the exception says ".UnknownHostException: citi.perfectomobile.com" but in your code you have "xyz.perfectomobile.com", is that intentional?

Comment: I don't see port number in the URL. Can you try with correct port number along with URL?

Comment: did the edit to xyz.perfectomobile.com. But we are concerned that this url is accessible through browser, but not through code. Also, we are trying to access this through VDI

Comment: @Vinod  I am connecting perfecto mobile cloud.For that I used
 driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://" + host + "/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub"), capabilities);
the same code is working from local.but not from VDI.